# uninitialized data segment of program memory

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory

In Uninitialized Data Segment, the kernel initialize the uninitialized variable to 0.

But if we directly use an uninitialized variable (for eg. int sum; and not int sum=0; ) and use it in program like sum=sum+n(n be any number), sum will take any garbage value.

So why the sum will take any garbage value if it has already been initialized to 0 by the kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking about the difference between compile-time initialization and run-time initialization. In the following C code:

```
int i;
int main() {
    int j;
    return i + j;
}
```

`i` is a globally scoped variable and so is default initialized to zero, which is achieved by including it in the data segment of the program. This will either be written as a block of initial values to the binary or it will describe to the loader the size of the block and the loader will flood-fill it with zeros when the executable starts.

`j`, however, is a local variable that will live in registers or on the stack. C and C++ choose not to default initialize these values, and so if you access them without initializing them, you will see the value that happens to be in their register/stack location.